# Force an Azure Resource Graoh to show 0 - KQL - Azure monitor

Tags: kql, azure-monitor

I want to create a pie chart showing the counts of open (not closed) alerts which is working. However, I want it to default to 0 in the chart when there is no alert for a particular severity

```
    alertsmanagementresources
|extend Sev = tostring(parse_json(properties.essentials.severity)),
        LastModifiedTime = todatetime(properties.essentials.lastModifiedDateTime)
| where tostring(parse_json(properties.essentials.alertState)) <> 'Closed'
| where resourceGroup =='ai-eazyfuel-eu-prd-rg'
| where Sev =='Sev0'
|where LastModifiedTime >=datetime(2022/07/26)
|summarize count() by Sev
```

Is this even possible because I understand there are no results to show but you know what end users are like

Comment: to clarify your desired outcome - you may want to provide a sample output/image of how you expect a pie chart to look, when some, or even all counts are zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's feasible to write the KQL query:

1. Azure Resource Graph uses only a limited subset of KQL which makes the query syntax cumbersome.
2. Azure Resource Graph cannot display 0 size slice.

P.S.
Please note the removal of unnecessary transformations of `properties` and the use of ISO format for datetime.

---

```
resources
| take          1
| mv-expand     severity = range(0,4) to typeof(string)
| project       severity = strcat("Sev", severity)
| join          kind=leftouter 
                (
                        alertsmanagementresources
                        | extend    severity                = tostring(properties.essentials.severity)
                                   ,lastModifiedDateTime    = todatetime(properties.essentials.lastModifiedDateTime)
                        | where     properties.essentials.alertState <> "Closed" 
                                and resourceGroup == "ai-eazyfuel-eu-prd-rg" 
                                and severity == "Sev0" 
                                and lastModifiedDateTime >= datetime("2022-07-26")
                        | summarize count() by severity
                ) on severity
| project       severity, count_ = coalesce(count_, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you - the casting is of interest elsewhere

Comment: The casting doesn't make sense regardless of the context. Everything extracted from a `dynamic` field, is by definition `dynamic. Given a dynamic input, `parse_json()/todynamic()` returns the dynamic value As Is, so the way you use `parse_json()` actually doesn't do anything.